# Instagram followers API not working in Postman

Tags: python, postman, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to get the Instagram followers using below API:

https://graph.instagram.com/33414280688/followers?access_token=IGQWRPZ

I have a valid access_token which I generated using the doc https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-access-tokens-and-permissions

The above API is returning below error:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "is_transient": true,
    "code": 2,
    "fbtrace_id": "AqJFIvFSEW7yYY7BJHsSeKL"
  }
}
```

In case I use another user-id it throws:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Tried accessing nonexisting field (followers) on node type (User)",
    "type": "IGApiException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "A0YzlvU7Tg37iSNIi9Af0FL"
  }
}
```

Can someone guide?